# Why isn't the MAC address of the default gateway sent in a DHCP acknowledgement?

Tags: mac-address, dhcp, arp

I've been reading about `DCHP` and `ARP`, and am confused about how your computer actually resolves the MAC address of the default gateway. The way I understand `DHCP` is this: When joining a network, your computer broadcasts a `DHCP discover` message to the machines on the `LAN`; the default gateway responds, telling you, among other things, the IP address it is giving you and its own IP address. But it doesn't respond with its `MAC address` (I checked in Wireshark).

My textbook says that your computer has an `ARP table` that just maps `IP addresses` to `MAC addresses` and how long those mappings remain valid. But say you haven't cached the `MAC address` of the router, either because the `TTL` expired or because you are first joining a network. My first instinct would be just sending out an `ARP` query, asking for the `MAC address` of the `IP address` given to you in the `DHCP response`. But that raises the question, why doesn't the `DHCP acknowledgement` just contain the default gateway's `MAC address` in addition to its `IP address`?

Comment: A DHCP server doesn't necessarily *know* what MAC address the client would need to use, in cases where the client is on a separate network.  Perhaps that could have been worked into the protocol somehow, with DHCP relay agents being required to change the MAC address field when forwarding a message to a different network - but it's far simpler just to use the standard ARP mechanism (that every device has to support anyway, in order to participate in an IP network) to discover the right MAC.